# StackBlitz and raw-loader

Tags: angular, stackblitz

Trying to publish my Angular app into StackBlitz via git-repo
but suddenly getting an error:

```
Can't find package:!!raw-loader!.
```

In my code I use it to load my .svg icons like this

```
import remove from '!!raw-loader!./icons/ban-solid.svg';
```

I did`t install any additional packages for it at my local machine. 
So, what is wrong?

Comment: I'm trying to figure out how to load/import a file as text using raw-loader as well. It is painfully exasperating that Stackblitz has this issue. Might they think nobody would want to load JSON, CVS, SVG, .md, .txt files or something??? Crazy.